# If/Else Program wont print index

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing a program that will print a list of numbers 1:n. However, every number divisible by 2 should be replaced with 'x' and every number divisible by 3 should be replaced with 'y'. Lastly, every number both divisible by 2 and 3 should be replaced with 'xy'. This is my code so far, I can get the function to print the correct result with my input. But it wont print the entire list of numbers. Instead I am just getting the end result (x,y, or xy) for the given input. Here is my code thus far with the output.

```
def replace(n):
    
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)

        if n%2== 0 and n%3 == 0:
            return 'xy'

        elif n%2==0:
            return 'y'

        elif n%3 == 0:
            return 'x'

        else: 
            print(i)
replace(12)

This is my output:

0
'xy'
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
1
x
y
x
5
xy
7
x
y
x
11
xy
```

Any advice would be appreciated, you guys rock!

Comment: Then why are you using `return` instead of `print`?

Comment: return terminates the loop and exits function

Comment: Also, `n` should be `i` in your conditional checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors:

1. At line 4, you `print(i)` - this means that each number will be printed
2. At lines 6, 9 and 12 you are using the `n` variable instead of `i` in the modulo operation
3. You want to check for numbers [1, n], but your loop checks for [0, 11]
4. You return instead of printing - the `return` keyword will stop the function's execution (and thus the loop) and return the value you specified. In case you are confused, consider the following example:

```
def get_number():
    return 5
    print("This will never print, as the function has already returned")


number = get_number() # number now equals 5, since it was returned

get_number() # 5 still gets returned, but is never assigned to a variable
```

Here is the code that gives the output that you mention above:

```
 def replace(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):

        if i%2 == 0 and i%3 == 0:
            print('xy')
        elif i%2 == 0:
            print('x')
        elif i%3 == 0:
            print('y')
        else:
            print(i)

replace(12)
```